# PHP if statements Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, if-statement

Im wanting to add an If statement to this code so that if one of the custom field options is set it does take the content to the homepage slider - If not then it does not.

Here is my code at the moment...

```
<?php query_posts('cat=22&posts_per_page=100');?>


<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>              
<li>
    <a href="http://www.url.co.uk<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'homelargeImage', true); ?>" title=""></a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank"></a>                        
    <div style="top:0px; left:0px; width:980px; height:515px;">
      <a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/perfomances/"><img src="http://www.url.co.uk/uploads<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'homeEventText', true); ?>" alt="" width="980" height="520" style="border:none;" /></a> 
    </div>
```

Anyone able to point me in the right direction to add in the If statement?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Stop using [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts). Wish wordpress wants to remove it in near future. Use the correct way, that is using [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming the following:

- get_post_meta($post->ID, 'homelargeImage', true) is the custom field options set you're talking about, if not, replace the get_post_meta($post->ID, 'homelargeImage', true) with whatever custom field that you're trying to set...
- that the two a href links that you had right after

  is the if / else statement you wanted to take the content to the homepage

With that in mind, here's what I got:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=22&posts_per_page=100');?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>              
<li>
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'homelargeImage', true)) { ?>
    <a href="http://www.url.co.uk<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'homelargeImage', true); ?>" title=""></a>
<?php } else {?>
    <a href="#" target="_blank"></a>   
<?php } 
    <div style="top:0px; left:0px; width:980px; height:515px;">
      <a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/perfomances/">
        <img src="http://www.url.co.uk/uploads<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'homeEventText', true); ?>" alt="" width="980" height="520" style="border:none;" />
      </a> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Stop using [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts). Wish wordpress wants to remove it in near future. Use the correct way, that is using [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)